# HANA SQL Script INSERT INTO with INNER JOIN can't insert values

Tags: inner-join, sql-insert, hana-sql-script

I'm quite new to SQL and hope you can help me with my problem.

I have a table called `Order_Status_Form_3` with the columns `Order_ID (KEY)`, `Customer_ID`, `Customer_Unique_ID`, `Status(KEY)` and `Date`.

The table is filled, except for the `Customer_Unique_ID` Column.

To fill this Column I need to reference the `Customer` table where the `Customer_ID` is linked to the `Customer_Unique_ID`, so the right IDs cover the right places. When the `Customer_ID` in `Order_Status_Form_3` equals the `Customer_ID` in the `Customer` table the given `Customer_Unique_ID` shall be inserted into the `Customer_Unique_ID` column in `Order_Status_Form_3`.

I tried to combine an `INSERT INTO` with a `SELECT` and `INNER JOIN`, but received an error message that says:

> "cannot insert NULL or update to NULL: Order_ID".

I guess it's not clear for the program where to insert the values found and it tries to insert into all columns. I searched for similar problems but could not find any satisfying answers for my specific problem.

Here's the code I used:

```
Insert Into "HXE_109"."Order_Status_Form_3" ("Customer_Unique_ID") 
Select customer."customer_unique_id"
From "HXE_109"."Customer" As customer
Inner Join "HXE_109"."Order_Status_Form_3" As OrderStatus3
On OrderStatus3."Customer_ID" = customer."customer_id"
```

I tried to specify the place to insert the values found by attaching a `WHERE` at the end, but received the same error.

```
Where OrderStatus3."Customer_ID" = customer."customer_id"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue and can tell me where my mistake is?

Thanks in advance for reading this long question and leaving an answer.

**Edit**

I tried using `update` but it seems like I cannot get it right.

`Update "HXE_109"."Order_Status_Form_3" 
Set "Customer_Unique_ID" = (Select customer."customer_unique_id"
                            From "HXE_109"."Customer" As customer
                            Inner Join "HXE_109"."Order_Status_Form_3" As OrderStatus3
                            On OrderStatus3."Customer_ID" = customer."customer_id")`

Now I get the following error:

> single row query returns more than one row

Do I need to use a `Where` condition here?

Sorry for my stupidity. :(

Comment: `INSERT` is for adding new row, seems that you want to use `UPDATE`. This error says that you're trying to insert row without value for `Order_ID` column (which doesn't accept `NULL`s)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this to me, i did not know that :) I tried to do it with `update` but it seems like I keep making mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

As I could follow the comments, what you want to do is running an UPDATE statement

Please check following DML command

```
Update "HXE_109"."Order_Status_Form_3" 
Set 
    "Customer_Unique_ID" = customer."customer_unique_id"
From "HXE_109"."Order_Status_Form_3" As OrderStatus3
Inner Join "HXE_109"."Customer" As customer
    On OrderStatus3."Customer_ID" = customer."customer_id"
```

If I try to explain the error messages:

"cannot insert NULL or update to NULL: Order_ID".

That is related with a field defined as NOT NULL. So in your target table ORDER_ID is defined as "not null", so in INSERT you have to provide a value for it or define it as an [identity field in your HANA table](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/hana-database-table-with-identity-column.aspx) definition

The second error: single row query returns more than one row

This is related with the case where SQL Engine expects a value not a set of values.
So the SELECT statement that you assign the results to Customer_Unique_ID field returns more than 1 value. In this case SQL engine raises an exception